# Compilation error during the filtering of zipped arrays using nested function

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10

I'm trying to filter zipped arrays using nested function, but I have got a compilation error related to the type of the variable "mergedRow"

Here is my example :

ScalaVersion = 2.10.4

```
val arrayOne : Seq[IndexedSeq[Double]] = Seq.empty
val arrayTow : Seq[IndexedSeq[String]]  = Seq.empty

(this.arrayOne , this.arrayTow).zipped.filter{
  mergedRow : (IndexedSeq[String], IndexedSeq[Double])=>

  // some processing
  true
}
```

The compilation error :

```
Error:(130, 51) type mismatch;
 found   : ((IndexedSeq[String], IndexedSeq[Double])) => Boolean
 required: (IndexedSeq[String], IndexedSeq[Double]) => Boolean
      mergedRow : (IndexedSeq[String], IndexedSeq[Double])=>
                                              ^
```

I don't know the origin of this error, so every help will be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `case`. It should look more like this:

```
(arrayOne , arrayTwo).zipped.filter{
    case (one, two) =>
       // filter predicate
}
```

The type arguments will produce a *fruitless type test* warning, so I omitted them. You can replace `case (one, two)` with `case mergedRow` if you wish, but doing operations on `one` and `two` is much cleaner than `mergedRow._1` and `mergedRow._2`.

Comment: Indeed using case(one,tow) is much cleaner than mergedRow._1 and mergedRow._2.
Thank you for your help :).